# Optimizing overlap between two reference frames

Tags: geometry, optimization

Let me share this little optimization problem with you:

I have two orthonormal sets of vectors on $\mathbb{R}^3$, related by some Euler angles $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ (corresponding to those of the first figure in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). The question is the following:

Which configurations, given by their Euler angles, maximize and minimize the sum of the absolute value of the cosines of the angles of every vector on one set with every vector in the other one (that is, the Euler angles that maximize and minimize the magnitude of the projections of the unit vectors in the direction of the first set of axes on the second's)?

For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it turns out that the sum of absolute values of cosines is actually minimal when the sets are parallel, and maximizes when every vector in one set forms 45 degrees with every vector of the other set.

Therefore, the question (as said before is): Which configurations, denoted by their Euler angles $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ are optimal and which are worst?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: Essentially by inspection, I found the following 96 configurations of which maximize the sum of absolute values of the projections

$$
    (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\frac{\pi}{2},\beta_1,\frac{\pi}{4}+m\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\notag\\
   (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\frac{\pi}{2},\pi-\beta_1,\frac{\pi}{4}+m\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
   (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\alpha_1+n\frac{\pi}{2},\beta_2,l\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha_1\right)\\
   (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\alpha_2+n\frac{\pi}{2},\beta_2,l\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha_2\right)
$$
for $n,\,m=0\dots3$, $l=1\dots8$, $\vartheta_1\approx1.2310$, $\vartheta_2\approx2.3005$, $\psi_1\approx0.4636$ and $\psi_2\approx1.1071$ (all angles in radians).

The amount of them is consistent with the symmetries of the problem, but I am still not sure if this is all of them or there are more. Additionally, it would be nice to have a (semi-)analytic derivation of $\alpha_{1,2}$ and $\beta_{1,2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! the minimum is obvious: when the two frames are parallel (each axis of one of them coincides with one axes of the other). in that case the sum of the projection of the unit vectors in the direction of the axes is 3.

Also, the maximum projection (understood as the sum of projections) will happen when the  sum of the absolute value of the 9 possible projections of each orthogonal vector of the rotated frame with each orthogonal vector of the original frame equals 5 (can't be larger than that) but the configuration that maximizes the sum of all the projections would be a bit more involved to obtain. I have no idea what it is or what symmetries it has! hope someone else replies :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, exactly, that is the exact point where I am. At the beginning I thought it would be natural to have the second reference frame oriented along the diagonals of the first, so each projection would be $1/\sqrt{3}$ and the total would be $9/\sqrt{3}\approx 5.2$. Unfortunately, the diagonals of a cube are not orthogonal. Exploring numerically I indeed have found that the maximum is 5 and some values of these maximizing configurations, but I was wondering if some analytic results exist. By the way, how did you know that the maximum was 5?

Comment: Oh, unfortunately I got the 5 by inspection too. Sorry about that. the 3 I got analytically but that one is trivial. I hope someone helps you out. I'm also curious! :)